# Jenkins - archive work space include dot files

Tags: ant, jenkins

When archiving a workspace in Jenkins I want to also archive all the files starting with a dot like .gitignore, my standard pattern of ** to copy everything ignores this. Which pattern should I use?

Answer (score 0):

I was being silly, there is a checkbox that needs checking "Override Default Ant Excludes"

Comment: @Terion Even bit late, but maybe some find this as well. The checkbox is on the `Archive for Clone Workspace SCM` action, below the drop-down box for selecting the `Archive method`.